# Dropdown NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Below code i have to ammend for adding a dropdown in my asp website. I have already added could you please check what is wrong.

```
Function collectEmailBodyText()
        Try
            Dim counterEnd As Integer = subActivated_HowManyControlsInAPanel()
            Dim counter As Integer = 0
            Dim tempPanelLabel As Label
            Dim tempPanelInputBox As TextBox
            Dim tempPanelDropDownBox As DropDownList
            Dim tempCollector As String
            Dim panelUsed As String = ""
            '* Find out which panel is used to collect panel data:
            panelUsed = view0_panelUsed.ToString
            Response.Write("<!-- " + panelUsed + " -->")
            '
            tempCollector = "<p><b>" + lbl_viewTitle0.Text + "</b>"
            tempCollector = tempCollector + "<br>" + lbl_view0_firstName.Text + ": " + txt_firstName.Text
            tempCollector = tempCollector + "<br>" + lbl_view0_surname.Text + ": " + txtSurName.Text
            tempCollector = tempCollector + "<br>" + lbl_view0_ContactNum.Text + ": " + txt_contactNum.Text
            '
            tempCollector = tempCollector + "<p><b>" + lbl_viewTitle1.Text + "</b>"
            tempCollector = tempCollector + "<br>" + lbl_view1_firstName.Text + ": " + txt_view1_firstname.Text
            tempCollector = tempCollector + "<br>" + lbl_view1_surname.Text + ": " + txt_view1_surname.Text
            tempCollector = tempCollector + "<br>" + lbl_view1_userID.Text + " " + txt_view1_userID.Text
            tempCollector = tempCollector + "<br>" + lbl_view1_workUnit.Text + ": " + ddl_view1_workunit.SelectedItem.Text + " :: " + ddl_view1_workunit.SelectedValue.ToString()
            tempCollector = tempCollector + "<br>" + lbl_view0_typeOfRequest.Text + ": " + ddl_view0_typeOfRequest.SelectedItem.ToString
            tempCollector = tempCollector + "<br>" + lbl_view0_workUnitLevel.Text + ": " + ddl_view0_workUnitLevel.SelectedItem.ToString + "<br>"
            '
            '* Collect panel data:
            Do
                counter = counter + 1
                tempPanelLabel = New Label
                tempPanelInputBox = New TextBox
                tempPanelDropDownBox = New DropDownList
                tempPanelLabel = form1.FindControl("lbl_" + panelUsed + "_label" + counter.ToString())
                tempPanelInputBox = form1.FindControl("txt_" + panelUsed + "_input" + counter.ToString())
                tempPanelDropDownBox = DirectCast(form1.FindControl(("txt_" & panelUsed & "_ddinput") + counter.ToString()), DropDownList)

                tempCollector = tempCollector + "<br>" + tempPanelLabel.Text
                'tempCollector = tempCollector + ": " + tempPanelInputBox.Text
                tempCollector = tempCollector + ": " + tempPanelDropDownBox.SelectedValue


            Loop Until counter = counterEnd
            '
            If storeSelected() = 0 Then
                tempCollector = tempCollector + "<p><b>" + lbl_viewTitle2.Text + "</b>"
                tempCollector = tempCollector + "<br>" + lbl_view2_ManagersEmailAddress.Text + ": " + txt_view2_ManagersEmailAddress.Text
            End If
            '
            Return tempCollector
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.ToString()
            Response.Write(ex.ToString())
        End Try

    End Function
```

Below is the extra line I added

```
tempPanelDropDownBox = DirectCast(form1.FindControl(("txt_" & panelUsed & "_ddinput") + counter.ToString()), DropDownList)
```

and I am getting the following error:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at WebApplication1._Default.collectEmailBodyText() in C:\v1.5_production_05June09\Default.aspx.vb:line 220

Comment: Why are you posting the question againa and again?

Comment: i didnt posted the code before ..please help

Comment: @SmartestVEGA: please update your original question with the code sample (there is an edit link to the right just under the tags) instead of posting a new one. It's really hard answering questions if they are spread out over multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to know which object is null given line numbers, but at a guess one of the lines in the form

```
tempPanelInputBox = form1.FindControl("txt_" + panelUsed + "_input" + counter.ToString())
```

is failing, this would be because the name generated by the part "txt_" + panelUsed + "_input" + counter.ToString() doesn't match a control within the form.

So, look at the line 220 within the file, and  check the control that it is looking for appears within the form.

After looking at it, I think the line

```
tempPanelDropDownBox = DirectCast(form1.FindControl(("txt_" & panelUsed & "_ddinput") + counter.ToString()), DropDownList)
```

should read

```
tempPanelDropDownBox = DirectCast(form1.FindControl(("txt_" & panelUsed & "_ddlinput") + counter.ToString()), DropDownList)
```

the difference being ddl in the name not dd (Based on assumption that you name drop downs ddl)

Comment: this is line 220
tempCollector = tempCollector + ": " + tempPanelDropDownBox.text

and i have selected a value in dropdown list in the form

Comment: in that case is it txt_ at the start? At the end of the day the string you generate to pass into the FindControl function doesn't match a controls name, can you give us where that particular drop down is created?

Comment: txt_panview3_ddinput1  

this is the dropdown control ID

Comment: when i select a option called store in another dropdown it will be diverted to a view and which will show the dropdown in question

before there was a textbox i have put aside a dropdown near to that . Later i want to remove the textbox

Comment: And if you break point on that line, then quick watch into the forms controls, you see a control with this name?

Comment: i guess if the loop runs , the name of dropdown for different views does not exists and hence throwing a error !

what about pulling out that dropdown reference line out of loop , i want this dropdown for only one view!

Comment: Ahh, if you only have one drop down, but this loop runs multiple times, then sure pull this line out of the loop, or something similar.  Does that work? (I assume you;; have to replace the counter.ToString() with just 1

Answer (score 1):

In your code, if a control with the name you are concatenating doesn't exist (or if your concatenation isn't quite right, for example) then you could get this error.

Perform the findcontrol function first and check it's not null before trying to obtain a value from it.

For debugging purposes, it may well be worth checking that "panelUsed" is what you're expecting. If it's an empty string because the variable hasn't been set correctly, this could cause your error.

Answer (score 1):

try using Debugger!
Go step by step and you'll find your error.